# Android Audio stereo pin functions

Tags: android

I have nothing to do with android programming or electronics but am extremely curious how this following setup has been achieved.

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/556341540/pressy-the-almighty-android-button
Right down in the FAQ, it states that audio is not blocked by the audio jack plug in. Neither the speaker no microphone are blocked.

1. How is that possible? (if I plug in a audio jack with nothing on the end, my phone will block audio and channel it through to the ear phones it thinks are connected
2. How does the normal mic work, with this audio pin slotted in? ...

I would really, love to understand how this is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a hardware thing. It's because of the Pressy app that, when installed, handles audio output.

Comment: thankyou. you are saying that with the stereo pin slotted in, the pressy app prevents audio output from being routed through to the audio jack, as well as the normal mic working.

Could you point me to a weblink where I could read about these 2 settings for a potential app I'd like to create. thanks so much

Comment: have a read here: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html

Comment: also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

Comment: Yes. wonderful. I got through to the audio manager. Its very nice. Basically, the app can set how audio out put is managed. however, i cannot see the setting for controlling mic input coming from headset mic or phone mic. I would want to keep the mic input coming from the main mic, not headset mic (as there wouldn't actually be a headset mic connected to the stereo pin)

Comment: Sorry about linking instead of giving answers but here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815850/forcing-mediarecorder-to-use-internal-microphone

Comment: nice! i navigated to mediarecorder.audiosource already. android seems quite intuitive and well explained actually. well, seems like this is the main problem. keeping audio source as internal mic as opposed to headset mic when stereo pin is plugged in. i wonder how the pressy guys did it.